# How to sort a list by creation date? (Python - OS library)

Tags: python, operating-system

I'd like to rename a list of video cuts in a folder (in my case /Desktop/Cuts/)
from:
xxx.mp4, yyy.mp4, ..., zzz.mp4
to:
1.mp4, 2.mp4, ..., 33.mp4.

1.mp4 will be the video that was first created in the folder. 2.mp4 will be the second, etc.

What I am doing now (please see code below) renames the video cuts in /Cuts/, but according to an order that I don't understand, and that is definitely NOT creation date. (it does not seem alphabetical, either)

```
import os
path = '/Users/ntelmaut/Desktop/Cuts/'

i = 1
for file in os.listdir(path):

    new_file_name = "{}.mp4".format(i)
    os.rename(path + file, path + new_file_name)

    #print path + file
    i = i+1
```

I have tried make a variable out of `os.listdir(path)` and to apply sorted() function, but to no avail yet (I am a newbie to Python - sorry).

Would love a pointer, here.

Thank you!

Comment: so the order of the files in the new folder will be oldest first?

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
import glob

import os
dirpath = '/Users/ntelmaut/Desktop/Cuts/'

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.mp4'))   
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)

for i, filename in enumerate(files, 1):
    try:
       os.rename(filename, "{0}.mp4".format(i))
    except OSError as e:
       print("OSError: ", e)
```

Comment: Thanks!
I did "import os", renamed dirpath "path" then removed the second ")" at the end of line 7 and I got it!

Comment: One thing though - files are being renamed AND moved in '/Users/ntelmaut/Desktop/'. Any idea why?

Comment: What is your dirpath?

Comment: right now I removed dirpath altogether and have:
https://codepen.io/ntelmaut/pen/YzyWdPm

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is what you want.

```
import os
path = '/Users/ntelmaut/Desktop/Cuts/'

def sort_key(file):
    return os.stat(file).st_ctime

files = os.listdir(path)
sorted_files = sorted((os.path.join(path, f) for f in files), key=sort_key)

i = 1
for file in sorted_files:
    new_file_name = f"{i}.mp4"
    os.rename(file, new_file_name)
    i += 1
```

A cleaner way would be to use the `pathlib` module.

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('/Users/ntelmaut/Desktop/Cuts/')

def sort_key(path):
    return path.stat().st_ctime

sorted_files = sorted(p.iterdir(), key=sort_key)

for idx, file in enumerate(sorted_files, 1):
    new_name = f"{idx}.mp4"
    file.rename(p / new_name)
```

Comment: You could use `enumerate` with `start=1` to get rid of the increment. Also, note to OP: I recommend you first `print` the result before actually renaming the files :)

Comment: sure I was trying to modify as little code as possible for OP